# разбить строку по пробелам golang

Tags: html, post, golang

Имеется форма:

```
    <form action="findById" method="post">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Найти</button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите Ф.И.О">
    </div>
    </form
```

Получаю стоку вида "Иванов Иван Иванович"

Подскажите пожалуйста как ее можно привести к следующему виду:

string fam = "Иванов"

string Name = "Иван"

string LastName = "Иванович"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете сделать это с помощью [функции Split из пакета strings](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split). Пример:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    arr := strings.Split("Иванов Иван Иванович", " ")
    fam := arr[0]
    Name := arr[1]
    LastName := arr[2]
    fmt.Println(fam, Name, LastName)
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @ЕвгенийГусев,  `len(arr)`

Comment: угу, уже прочитал, в других языках привык к ar.length

Answer (score 1):

Мне удобней показалась функция [Fields](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Fields)

```
strings.Fields(s string) []string
```

Она побыстрее будет и Split генерит пустые строки при наличии нескольких пробелов.